# My hover animation is not working properly

Tags: html, css

By using `nth-child(1) & nav .start-home,a:nth-child(1):hover~.animation` I should define the properties of home link and it's animation like it's width and position. But to adjust the width and position of the animation of the home link I have to make adjustments in `nnth-child(2)`. And same goes for about link I need to do adjustments in `nth-child(3)`.

In the end I can make the animation work for the last sign-in link. Also the animation is not running properly, it's breaking in the middle. Run the code and you will get better understanding of my problem.

```css
body{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: rgb(255, 238, 238);
}
nav{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0;       
    width: 100%; 
    height: 50px; 
    background-color: #04111ffa;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}
nav a{
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: seashell;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 50px;
    z-index: 5;
    text-align: center;
}
nav .animation{
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(58, 233, 218);
    border-radius: 10%;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
a:nth-child(1){
    width: 150px;
    left: 0;
}
nav .start-home,a:nth-child(1):hover~.animation {
    width: 80px;
    left: 70px;
}
a:nth-child(2){
    left: 50px;
    width: 150px;
}
nav .start-about,a:nth-child(2):hover~.animation {
    width: 80px;
    left: 70px;
}
a:nth-child(3){
    left: 70px;
    width: 120px;
}
nav .start-contact,a:nth-child(3):hover~.animation {
    width: 80px;
    left: 140px;
}
a:nth-child(4){
    left: 90px;
    width: 170px;
}
nav .start-privacy-policy,a:nth-child(4):hover~.animation {
    width: 90px;
    left: 225px;
}
a:nth-child(5){
    left: 110px;
    width: 200px;
}
nav .start-docs,a:nth-child(5):hover~.animation {
    width: 145px;
    left: 315px;
}
a:nth-child(6){
    left: 130px;
    width: 100px;
}

.search-container{
    float: right;
}
input[type=text]{
    padding: 6px;
    margin-top: 13px;
    font-size: 17px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.search-container button{
    float: right;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    margin-top: 13px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    font-size: 17px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: rgb(58, 233, 218);
}
.search-container button:hover{
    background-color: rgb(35, 168, 157);
}

.icon{
    color: white;
    z-index: 5;
}
.search-container{
    float: right;
}
.links{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DyZ88mC6Up2uqS4h/KRgHuoeGwBcD4Ng9SiP4dIRy0EXTlnuz47vAwmeGwVChigm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="navbar.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        
    <nav>
        <div class="links">
        <span class="icon fas fa-bars"></span>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
        <a href="#">Sign-in</a>
        <div class="animation start-home"></div>
    </div>
        <div class="search-container">
            <form>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="search" class="searchbar">
                <button type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i><span class="text">Search</span></button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, then perhaps this example can help you:

```js
const animationElement = document.querySelector('.links .animation');
const defaultElement = document.querySelector('.links a'); // set default element !

const slideToElement = (el) => {
  if (el) {
    animationElement.style.left = el.offsetLeft + 'px';
    animationElement.style.width = el.offsetWidth + 'px';
  } else {
    animationElement.style.removeProperty('left');
    animationElement.style.removeProperty('width');
  }
}

// tracking all hovers on "a" links
document.querySelector('.links').addEventListener('mouseover', (ev) => ev.target.matches('a') && slideToElement(ev.target))

// tracking leaving the links area
document.querySelector('.links').addEventListener('mouseleave', () => slideToElement(defaultElement))

slideToElement(defaultElement); // setting the slide to the default position
```

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: rgb(255, 238, 238);
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #04111ffa;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

nav a {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: seashell;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 50px;
  z-index: 5;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

nav .animation {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(58, 233, 218);
  border-radius: 10%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}

a:nth-child(1) {
  width: 150px;
  left: 0;
}

input[type=text] {
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 13px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.search-container button {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-top: 13px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(58, 233, 218);
}

.search-container button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(35, 168, 157);
}

.icon {
  color: white;
  z-index: 5;
}

.search-container {
  float: right;
}

.links {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DyZ88mC6Up2uqS4h/KRgHuoeGwBcD4Ng9SiP4dIRy0EXTlnuz47vAwmeGwVChigm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="navbar.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>

    <nav>
      <div class="links">
        <span class="icon fas fa-bars"></span>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
        <a href="#">Sign-in</a>
        <div class="animation start-home"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="search-container">
        <form>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="search" class="searchbar">
          <button type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i><span class="text">Search</span></button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

This solution is made in JS, which made it possible to remove excess from CSS and not depend on pre-set CSS values.

I hope this can help somehow.

Comment: Yes your code is working and my problem is solved. But can you give me the reason why my code wasn't working??

Comment: @AbhranilDas, Consider two elements from your example: "ABOUT" and "CONTACT".
When you hover over "ABOUT", the selector: "a:nth-child(3):hover~.animation" becomes active. But when you move the cursor to "CONTACT", first you remove the hover from "ABOUT" and the above selector becomes inactive - and the transition is triggered in the opposite (i.e., in the default position) side. And when you have already pointed to the "CONTACT" itself, there is a transition already to this element. I.e. there is a chain "default->ABOUT->default->CONTACT", and not "default->ABOUT->CONTACT", as you wanted.

Comment: @AbhranilDas, You can avoid this only with CSS if the elements stand close to each other, without indentation. For example, if you make links block elements with a large indentation and text alignment in the center. But this is very inconvenient with absolute positioning of the elements.
Otherwise, you'd better use JS and control the mouseover/mouseout/mouseleave events more subtly, as is done in the example provided.
I hope I managed to explain it somehow.